# four types of beings (reference searched)

Tags: satipatthana

I remember hearing somewhere about 4 types of beings in relation with the satipatthana sutta and that for each group one of the satipatthanas is most important/suitable to practice. Can somebody please give me a reference from the suttas or commentaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. affective, slow temperament - body
2. intellectual, fast temperament - mental contents
3. affective, fast temperament - sensations
4. intellectual speculation, slow temperament - mind

Sourced from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satipatthana_Sutta

This is not found in the Suttas but in the commentaries. This is taken from Papañcasudani